# Attribute Error: module 'Orange.widgets.gui' has no attribute 'WebviewWidget'

Tags: word-cloud, orange

`Attribute Error: module 'Orange.widgets.gui' has no attribute 'WebviewWidget'`

[image]

Part of the source code importing WebviewWidget

[image]

When I tried importing the module `Orange.widgets.utils.webview` and when I look for WebviewWidget attribute...there is none...only a description about it. Here is the text in the description of the module:

> DESCRIPTION
> This module holds our customized WebView that integrates HTML, CSS & JS
> into Qt. WebviewWidget provides a somewhat uniform interface (_WebViewBase) around either WebEngineView (extends QWebEngineView) or
> WebKitView (extends QWebView), as available.

Comment: I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, pasting some code (not in images!!!), errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary in order for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). Hang in there. You'll be great at this. ;)

Comment: Thanks...I figured the problem was QtWebKit was not installed in my system...Some sources said QtWebKit was deprecated in Qt5.7 and that the bleeding edge QtWebEngine is hard to install...I just used QtWebKit and WordCloud Widget worked fine...

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!!! The problem was QtWebKit was not installed in my system...installed it and it worked fine...I also included the pyqt5 and debug package...